# CSS <1px gap between styled list menu in Chrome

Tags: css

As you'll see in the screenshot linked to below, I'm encountering strange behaviour when using Chrome 39.0.2171.95. A smaller than 1px gap appears between the styled list items. It looks fine in Firefox and IE.

I hadn't noticed it until I started using a device with retina display, so I would be interested to find out how many others see the same as me.

It doesn't use inline-block, and removing the space between each `<li>` is not possible as the three-tiered menu is generated by WordPress (and I doubt it is a solution here). Using negative margins hides the gap, but as a workaround and not a solution it causes other issues (it moves the sub-menus out of place).

**Screenshot:** http://i58.tinypic.com/m9rkmf.jpg

**Link:** http://www.tolkiensociety.org/

This is the current CSS:

```
#mainmenu {
background:#333333;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:960px;
}
#mainmenu.fixed {
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:100;
height:43px;
}
#mainmenu > ul {
padding-left:124px;
}
#mainmenu ul {
height:43px;
list-style:none;
position:relative;
}
#mainmenu ul li {
float:left;
}
#mainmenu ul li a {
display:block;
padding:12px 10px;
border-bottom:4px solid #00A33E;
color:#fefefe;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:300;
height:15px;
}
#mainmenu ul li:hover > a {
background:#222222;
}
#mainmenu .menu-item-1128 > a {
border-bottom: 4px solid #82c4e5;
}
#mainmenu .menu-item-644 > a {
border-bottom: 4px solid #e33417;
}
#mainmenu .menu-item-62 > a {
border-bottom: 4px solid #78bf32;
}
#mainmenu .menu-item-91 > a {
border-bottom: 4px solid #00A33E;
}
#mainmenu .menu-item-81 > a {
border-bottom: 4px solid #d99f3c;
}
#mainmenu .menu-item-739 > a {
border-bottom: 4px solid #F1654F;
}
#mainmenu ul ul {
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:39px;
z-index:9999;
min-width:200px;
}
#mainmenu ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
}
#mainmenu ul ul li {
float:none;
position:relative;
}
#mainmenu ul ul li a {
padding:12px 10px;
border:0;
color:#fefefe;
text-transform:none;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:400;
height:15px;
white-space:nowrap;
background-color:#222;
}
#mainmenu ul ul li a:hover {
background-color:#111;
}
#mainmenu ul ul ul {
position:absolute;
left:100%;
top:0;
}
#mainmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
background:#111;
}
#mainmenu ul ul ul li a {
background-color:#111;
}
#mainmenu ul ul ul li a:hover {
background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: If you can't adjust the HTML, and margins won't work, then the only thing left is javascript to search for the element and position it that way. Whether you want to go through all that, I don't know.

Comment: using latest Chrome Version: 39.0.2171.95 m this behavior doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

Resset the UL and LI as shown below  to bring the padding and margin of the listed to zero.

```
ol, ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**Note:** Add the above to the very top of your CSS file. That way, unless if otherwise set, the padding and margin will be zero.

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm afraid. These were already reset at the top of my [Stylesheet](http://www.tolkiensociety.org/wp-content/themes/tolksoc/style.css).

Answer (score 0):

Is your browser zoom at 100%? I recently had a similar case, and I found out the little gap was because the page was slightly zoomed in.

Comment: Yes, it's set at 100%. The gap shows up below 100% too.